# emacs init - splitting window and opening files next to each other

Tags: emacs, init

I am trying to customize my Emacs init file in such a way that Emacs opens with two windows split and the ansi-term opened in one side and my init file on the other side. Now, the function I wrote (`switch-to-next-window`) works perfectly if Emacs is open already.

I was hoping to make the cursor switch to the other window and then open my init file there. However, if I try to run this upon start-up (actually after start up, at least this is what I am thinking) I get the following error: `window-live-p, nil`

I am gessing that there is no "next window". But I just don't know a work around here since I do think that I am only calling my function after Emacs has fully started up? If anyone could point me to where I am going wrong in my logic, that would be great!

```
(split-window-horizontally)
(setq initial-buffer-choice "*ansi-term*")

(defun switch-to-next-window ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((next-window (get-buffer-window (other-buffer (current-buffer) t))))
    (select-window next-window)))

(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook (lambda ()(ansi-term "/bin/bash")))
(with-eval-after-load "~/.emacs.d/init.el"
  (switch-to-next-window)
  (setq initial-buffer-choice "~/.emacs.d/init.el"))
```

Comment: You might want to consider using [desktop](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Saving-Emacs-Sessions.html) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `initial-buffer-choice` after the initial buffer has been opened won't have any effect.

What helps is putting everything into the `emacs-startup-hook` and using the `find-file-other-window` function:

```el
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook
          (lambda ()
            (ansi-term "/bin/bash")
            (split-window-horizontally)
            (find-file-other-window "~/.emacs.d/init.el")))
```

Comment: thank you that works perfectly! still struggling to find al those available functions in emacs